# What is the font from the intro of "The Lord of the Rings"

Tags: font-identification

(I've read [the related answer on meta](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions).)

What I'm looking for is the font used in the intro to "The Lord of the Rings". It is at the beginning of [this clip from the italian version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RyyuYzN3P-w) and [this one from the english version](https://youtu.be/BhjDnrw34QA?t=62); the spanish version uses [this](https://roadtosalina.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/2003a-32.jpg). Given the very similar words, it seems that the spanish and italian version share exactly the same font, but I'm not dead sure that the english version uses, the same (even if I think so). Anyway I need the italian-version font.

[image: Here's the spanish title]

With [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/)'s *Font by appearance* tool I've found some similar-looking fonts, but anyway the similartity is really loose.

The other tools really didn't help me.

That it could be a non-font is a real possibilty; on the other hand, reapeted letters are pretty much the same, and the different filling and jagged borders could have been added to the letters of the font.

It's a serif font, isn't it?

Comment: Without looking anything up, I'd describe these as "uncial" fonts.  So, you could look up uncial fonts, and [search through them](https://www.dafont.com/search.php?q=uncial).  Other uncial fonts may be described as "Irish" or "Celtic" so it's worth searching these terms as well.

Comment: Also might be worthwhile googling "lord of the ring fonts"!

Comment: @BillyKerr, not really useful results, unfortunately. _Aniron_ seems close at first sight, but it's very different, in fact.

Comment: I think you might be expecting too much to get an exact match, since it might not be an actual font. It's possible the uncial letters were created by hand. I obviously don't know what skills you have in calligraphy, but it might be better to go down that route.

Answer (score 2):

There's a web page with all the typography info: http://tatesha.com/Tolkien/tLotR.html

According to this page it's not a font

[image]

It's more than factible that it's not a font: have a look at the small caps "s" and "n" and compare them with the Spanish version in your image.

Comment: I've seen that page too. Do you think it's reliable? :(